# Creating a partial order from a total order with a concurrency oracle

Tags: algorithms, partial-order

I have a total order represented as a Hasse diagram (basically a linked list of ordered elements) and a concurrency oracle.

The concurrency orracle is a function, that tells me which pairs of elements of the total order, are concurrent - should not be ordered.

My goal is to use the information provided by the oracle to construct a Hasse diagram of the new (potentialy partial) order by modifying the input Hasse diagram.

Expressed mathematically: I want to compute the transitive closure of my total order Hasse diagram. Remove all its pairs/arcs that are present in the concurrency oracle. Finally find the transitive reduction of this graph - the Hasse diagram of my (potentialy partial) order.

I have implemented a naive solution to this problem, but the runtime scales very poorly. I am looking for a more efficient solution.

The naive solution works as follows:

- represent the total order Hasse diagram as a graph, with the ordering as directed edges, that lead from the smaller element to the larger element (a "preceeds" relation). I do not store the implicit transitive edges.
- place all the edges into a queue
- while the queue is not empty do:

  - take the first edge from the queue
  - if the concurrency oracle says the two elements are ordered, proceed to the next iteration
  - if the concurrency oracle says the two elements should not be ordered, remove the edge from the graph and add a new edges as follows (make the implicit transitive edges explicit):

    - for each element that preceeds the source of the removed edge, add a new edge to the destination of the removed edge
    - for each element that succeeds the destination of the removed edge, add a new edge from the source of the removed edge
  - append all the new edges into the queue
- remove any duplicate edges between elements

For example I might have the following total order Hasse diagram as input:

```
X --> A --> B --> C --> Y
```

along with a concurrency oracle, that says that `B` is concurrent with `A` and `C`. i.e. all pairs `(A,B), (B,A), (B,C), (C,B)` should be removed.

The expected result would be the following Hasse diagram:

```
X --> A --> C --> Y
 \               /
  \_____> B _>__/
```

I tried looking online for a solution, but could not find any relevant results with the keywords I used.

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a "strict partial order representation" or by a "concurrency oracle" or "concurrent".  Can you please define all terms in your post? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set for standard terminology.

Comment: @D.W. I have restated the question. Hopefully it is more clear now

Comment: "tells me which pairs of elements of the total order, are concurrent - not ordered" - the very definition of a total order is that all pairs of elements are ordered.  I don't understand what you are looking for.

Comment: "create a strict partial order from a strict total order" - a total order already *is* a partial order, so I don't understand why you need to do anything.

Comment: "compute the transitive closure of my total order relation" - a total order is already transitively closed.

Comment: @D.W. Sure a total order is a partial order. The whole point is that I want to lose information. If we do a transitive reduction on a total order, we create a "linked list" of elements, that can with a transitive closure reconstruct the total order. If we remove some elements of the total order, it might not be a total order anymore. I have the Hasse diagram of the total order and a set of arcs that are to be removed as input. And I want the Hasse diagram of the (potentialy) partial order after the removal of the arcs as output. Should I try to restate the question again using Hasse diagrams?

Comment: I think it would help to give a specification of what problem you want the algorithm to solve.  A helpful way to do that is to describe the inputs to the algorithm (a total order and a list of pairs of elements?  how is the total order represented?), and describe the output.  I was not previously aware that there is a set of arcs to be removed as part of the input.  Also, you should specify the desired output.  I don't know what the word "concurrent" means here so I suggest trying to express it in another way.

Comment: It might help to express the desired output using mathematics, rather than words.  Suppose $\le$ is the total input provided as input, and $(v_1,w_1),\dots$ are the arcs to remove, and $\sqsubseteq$ is the partial order you want to output.  How is $\sqsubseteq$ defined, in terms of the inputs?  Is there a concise mathematical way to specify it?  Or are there some conditions it must satisfy, or a concise algorithm to compute it?  The "naive solution" is long and challenging to follow.

Comment: @Minop The usage of "oracle" is misleading. An oracle is used to give answers online.  If so, the algorithm can simply be "start from the directed graph of a total order. For each edge, remove it if the oracle says the two elements in the edge should not be ordered." basically.

Comment: Here is a way to phrase the problem. "Design an algorithm that given a complete directed acyclic graph (DAG) $(V,E)$ as well as a set $F\subseteq E$, returns a transitive DAG $(V,M)$ such that $M\subseteq E$, $M\cap F=\emptyset$ and for any transitive DAG $(V, D)$ with $M\subsetneq D\subseteq E$, $D\cap F\not=\emptyset$."

Comment: Or the following description. "Describe an algorithm that given a total order $(V, \prec)$ and a set $F\subseteq V\times V$, returns a partial order $(V,\prec')$ such that if $u\prec' v$, then $u\prec v$ and $(u, v)\notin F$. Furthermore, no proper extension of $\prec'$ will satisfy the same condition."

Comment: I avoided "Hasse diagram" since it is easy to compute the Hasse diagram of a DAG or a partial order. The problem could be summarized as an anti-version of topological sort. Or did I misread your intention?

Comment: @JohnL. I was not familiar with the term "topological sort", but you have unterstood my intentions correctly. I am looking for an anti-version of topological sort. Or more precisely, I am looking for a more efficient implementation, than the one I am currently running. Since I am looking for efficiency, the Hasse diagram representation seems good to me, since I can store a total order of n elements in O(n), instead of O(n²), which is the case for a complete DAG. I will think about this again and will restate my question later.

Comment: There can be multiple results. For example, given total order $a\prec b\prec c\prec d$ and $F=\{(a,c),(b,d)\}$, we may obtain $a\prec' b$, $a\prec' d$ and $c\prec'd$.  We may obtain $a\prec' d$ and $b\prec' c$ instead.

Comment: @JohnL.I don't see how that is the case. the total order A < B < C < D consists of 7 ordered pairs. When you remove (A, C) and (B, D), none of the remaining pairs are transitive, so the transitive reduction would not remove anything and you more-or-less end up with the original order (except the (A, D) pair becoming explicit). Or am I missunderstanding something?